# Dishwasher chassis outputting an AC voltage

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, grounding, dishwasher, uk

I've recently noticed that touching the metal interior of my dishwasher gives me a slight tingling. I put that (stupidly) to static electricity.

For "fun" I then decided to touch a finger on the metal interior and another finger on my sink. Felt an AC voltage running through my body. The current wasn't painful, but it was uncomfortable and made my fingers twitch slightly.

In the UK, all metal appliances **must** be earthed (grounded for those across the pond). Touching other areas of the metal chassis revealed that these are not providing an electric current.

What I am most concerned about is that my fuse box (circuit breaker/RCD box) is not tripping. Surely it should detect that some current is flowing out of the electric socket and not returning, right?

Comment: Your fuse box doesn't react to "some" current. It reacts to _a lot_ of current. Have you looked at the dishwasher's connection box yet? Maybe there's a loose connector that has left a wire resting against the enclosure.

Comment: It sounds like the dishwasher and plug don't share the same ground. You should have continuity (0 Ohms) between the chassis and the ground pin of your plug. If you do, then it's possible that the ground wire in the cable to the receptacle is not actually connected to the plug/jbox (I don't know what your locality requires). The circuit breaker might not trip with such a low current. I doubt if it's on a GFCI breaker circuit and the plug probably isn't GFCI, either. Search for "Appliance Ground Fault" for some solutions.

Comment: By the way, that tingle was line voltage at a few amps. A tenth of an amp across your heart can stop it. Turn off that circuit and leave it off until the problem is solved.

Comment: Weird, and that didn't kill you?? Try soaking your fingers in salt water for a few minutes and try it again. That should kill you!  I joke, but electric shock situations like this are extremely fickle to local conditions, and often you luck into having enough impedance to not die.  That is no  guarantee of future luck!

Comment: "Surely it should detect that some current is flowing out of the electric socket and not returning, right?" - not if it doesn't have a path to ground sufficient enough to make it trip. You'll *know* when that happens, but not if it isn't GFCI'ed (aka: an RCD, as I understand them, or are they more like AFCIs?) because then you get electrocuted (the British definition if you're lucky: shocked; the American one if you're not: dead). - Electricity is not for "fun", so even if you **ask us how to fix this**, I'd decline.

Comment: @Ring In the UK, metal appliances MUST have all exterior metal connected to the socket's Earth (Ground).

Comment: @Harper That is a good point. I had wet fingers at the time, too, as I had just finished washing the dishes.

Comment: @Mazura In the UK, it doesn't rely on detecting a voltage through ground (if that's what you mean). It detects a difference between the current flowing out through Line and in through Neutral. I believe our downstairs appliance ring trips at 30mA, so it wasn't enough to trip our "fuse" (RCD).

Comment: True. "a path to ground [or a load] sufficient enough [to unbalance the neutral]." - less than .03 amps is what you felt, or it isn't GFCI'ed, or the breaker isn't working properly. None of this would matter if it was properly grounded. - Ensure there's a good ground. Then replace the breaker if it pops. Then replace the dishwasher.

Comment: @Mazura Post an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: @DavidWheatley, That's the same as here, but that doesn't stop the connection from breaking.

Comment: From reading up on RCD in the past they have a 30ma trip point if the leakage is sensed for 300ms. A leakage of 150ma must trip in 40 ms so you can get a big jolt without tripping an RCD and it is still fine. Testing it monthly would be a good idea, on this side of the pond we have a lower level trip point but the devices are on individual branch circuits so only 1 circuit trips at a lower current imbalance not as big of a shock 5ma is the trip threshold here but not all circuits are required to have GFCI protection here.